# Difference in Function Pointers and regular calling

Tags: c++, function, pointers

We had a homework assignment which is over now and the professor gave us the solutions. The problem was just to come up with a situation where we could use function pointers and the code it.

His example is this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int dvalue(int x)
{
  return x*x;
}
int tvalue(int x)
{
  return x*x*x;
}
void printValue(int (*fptr)(int), int x)
{
  cout << fptr(x) << endl;
}

int main()
{
int (*pfnc)(int);
int value = 10;
pfnc = dvalue;
printValue(pfnc, 10);
}
```

My questions are, is that the same thing as doing this:

```
int main()
{
cout << devalue(10) << endl;
}
```

And why do we use them? Do they use less memory? Is it just so we can call more than one function to a parameter or another function to make it simpler? 
It seems that they are more complicated, at least for a beginning programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My questions are, is that the same thing as doing this: [...]

In a nutshell, yes.

> And why do we use them?

In fact, we don't use them too often, especially in C++. We do use them somewhat more frequently in C.

Nonetheless, it is useful to understand function pointers. Some examples of classical uses are:

- telling [`qsort()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html) how to compare array elements;
- specifying which function to run when [starting a new thread](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/pthread_create.html).

Comment: So it's not something necessary, just a good thing to know for the future?

Comment: As your understanding of class design, object-orientation and abstraction improves,  you are more likely to look toward such concepts.

Comment: @user3289902: Sometimes they *are* necessary, just not very often. I would consider them a pretty advanced feature of C++ and would not teach them early on. On the other hand, I would expect anyone who claims proficiency in C++ to have a good grasp of function pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Why use function pointer?

> There are several cases where pointers to function can be of use. One
>   of the most common is the case where you are writing a function to
>   perform a task (such as sorting an array), but you want the user to be
>   able to define how a particular part of that task will be performed
>   (such as whether the array is sorted in ascending or descending
>   order). Let’s take a closer look at this problem as applied
>   specifically to sorting, as an example that can be generalized to
>   other similar problems.
>
> All sorting algorithms work on a similar concept: the sorting
>   algorithm walks through a bunch of numbers, does comparisons on pairs
>   of numbers, and reorders the numbers based on the results of those
>   comparisons. Consequently, by varying the comparison (which can be a
>   function), we can change the way the function sorts without affecting
>   the rest of the sorting code.

Although its used often in sorting, it has other uses such as [allowing callbacks when loading from a resource like a database.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1758585/866930)

**More succinctly, you have the benefit of being able to dynamically reference previously defined functions on the fly by simply pointing to them, and of course calling them.**

REFERENCE:

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/78-function-pointers/