# enum type check in C/gcc

Tags: c, gcc, enums

See the simple example below. When a function returning one `enum` is assigned to a variable of a different `enum` I don't get any warning even with `gcc -Wall -pedantic`. Why is it not possible for a C compiler to do type checking on `enum`s? Or is it `gcc` specific? I don't have access to any other compiler right now to try it out..

```
enum fruit {
APPLE,
ORANGE
};

enum color {
RED,
GREEN
};

static inline enum color get_color() {
    return RED;
}

int main() {
    enum fruit ftype;
    ftype = get_color();
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This declaration:

```
enum fruit {
    apple,
    orange
};
```

declares three things: a type called `enum fruit`, and two enumerators called `apple` and `orange`.

`enum fruit` is actually a distinct type.  It's compatible with some implementation-defined integer type; for example, `enum fruit` might be compatible with `int`, with `char`, or even with `unsigned long long` if the implementation chooses, as long as the chosen type can represent all the values.

The enumerators, on the other hand, are constants of type `int`.  In fact, there's a common trick of using a bare `enum` declaration to declare `int` constants without using the preprocessor:

```
enum { MAX = 1000 };
```

Yes, that means that the constant `apple`, even though it was declared as part of the definition of `enum fruit`, isn't actually of type `enum fruit`.  The reasons for this are historical.  And yes, it would probably have made more sense for the enumerators to be constants of the type.

In practice, this inconsistency rarely matters much.  In most contexts, discrete types (i.e., integer and enumeration types) are largely interchangeable, and the implicit conversions usually do the right thing.

```
enum fruit { apple, orange };
enum fruit obj;      /* obj is of type enum fruit */
obj = orange;        /* orange is of type int; it's
                        implicitly converted to enum fruit */
if (obj == orange) { /* operands are converted to a common type */
    /* ... */
}
```

But the result is that, as you've seen, the compiler isn't likely to warn you if you use a constant associated with one enumerated type when you mean to use a different one.

One way to get strong type-checking is to wrap your data in a struct:

```
enum fruit { /* ... */ };
enum color { /* ... */ };
struct fruit { enum fruit f; };
struct color { enum color c; };
```

`struct fruit` and `struct color` are distinct and incompatible types with no implicit (or explicit) conversion between them.  The drawback is that you have to refer to the `.f` or `.c` member explicitly.  (Most C programmers just count on their ability to get things right in the first place -- with mixed results.)

(`typedef` doesn't give you strong type checking; despite the name, it creates an alias for an existing type, not a new type.)

(The rules in C++ are a little different.)

Answer (score 7):

Probably most of us understand the underlying causes ("the specification says it must work"), but we also agree that this is a cause of a lot of programming errors in "C" land and that the struct wrapping workaround is gross.  Ignoring add-on checkers such as lint, here's what we have:

- GCC ([4.9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/), 2014-04-22): No warning available.
- Microsoft `cl` (18.0): No warning available.
- Clang (3.5): *Yes*, [-Wenum-conversion](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wanon-enum-enum-conversion)

Comment: All hail Apple/LLVM.  I believe these 3 compilers cover pretty much all the major OSes (iOS, Android, Microsoft, OSX), but any other interesting updates are appreciated.  I believe a previous post mentions icc, but I don't have access to that.

Answer (score 4):

`gcc` decided not to warn (as does `clang`) but `icc` (Intel compiler) would warn in this situation. If you want some additional type checking for `enum` types, you can pass your code to some static code checker software like `Lint` that is able to warn in such cases.

`gcc` decided it was not useful to warn for implicit conversions between `enum` types but note also that C doesn't require the implementation to issue a diagnostic in case of an assignment between two different `enum` types. This is the same as for the assignment between any arithmetic type: diagnostic is not required by C. For example, `gcc` would also not warn if you assign a `long long` to a `char` or a `short` to a `long`.

Answer (score 4):

10 years after this question was asked, GCC can do it now:

`gcc -Wextra main.c`

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:17:11: warning: implicit conversion from ‘enum color’ to ‘enum fruit’ [-Wenum-conversion]
   17 |     ftype = get_color();
```

Comment: Do what? Type checking?

Comment: What version of GCC? [GCC 11.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-11/)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Type checking on enums, and GCC 10.1.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `enum`s in C are simply a group of unique integer constants, that save you from having to `#define` a whole bunch of constants. It's not like C++ where the `enum`s you create are of a specific type. *That's just how C is.*

It's also worth noting that the actual size used to represent `enum` values depends on the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

An enum in C is basically handled like an integer. It's just a nicer way to use constants.

```
  // this would work as well
  ftype = 1;
```

You can also specify the values:

```
  enum color {
     RED=0,GREEN,BLUE
  } mycolor;

  mycolor = 1; // GREEN
```

Answer (score 1):

The GCC guys always have a reason not to do something.

Use Clang with options [`-Wenum-conversion`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wanon-enum-enum-conversion) and [`-Wassign-enum`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wassign-enum).

Comment: Apparently `gcc` guys also have a reason to downvote when they get offended.  I guess criticizing isn't considered PC on this site.  Anyway, I'm upvoting because you provide useful info on how to get `enum` type checking, which is one question that was originally asked.  Luckily for me, nobody can downvote my comment. ;-)

Comment: gcc supports the `-Wenum-conversion` option starting with release 10. (I didn't downvote, but if I had it would have been because of the first sentence.)