# What is the point of allowing an identifier for enum?

Tags: c, enums

Why doesn't the compiler complain when I try to assign incorrect values to variable `a` of type `enum answer`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    enum answer {NO, YES};
    enum gender {MALE, FEMALE};

    enum answer a = 5; /* Assign an invalid value. */
    printf("answer: %d\n", a);

    a = MALE; /* Assign a value of wrong type */
    printf("answer: %d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra enum.c 
$ ./a.out
answer: 5
answer: 0
```

If `enum` doesn't lead to type-checking, then what is the point of having the syntax as:

```
enum [identifier] {enumerator-list}
```

I used `answer` and `gender` as the identifier for my enum. What is the point of allowing this syntax?

I mean this code could be very well written as

```
enum {NO, YES};
enum {MALE, FEMALE};
```

What is the point of allowing this syntax?

```
enum answer {NO, YES};
enum gender {MALE, FEMALE};
```

Comment: It's a warning, not an error, at least in C++99

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597426/enum-type-check-in-c-gcc

Comment: clang gives a warning if `-Wconversion` is enabled for the "assign a value of wrong type" line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why doesn't the compiler complain when I try to assign incorrect values to variable `a` of type `enum answer`?

Because in C, an `enum` is practically equivalent to an `int`. It was standarized like it, and simply too many programs rely on that behavior for it to change.

In C++, they are distinct types and the compiler complains:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra a.c
a.c: In function 'int main()':
a.c:8:24: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'main()::answer' [-fpermissive]
a.c:11:14: error: cannot convert 'main()::gender' to 'main()::answer' in assignment
```

> What is the point of allowing this syntax?

My quick guess would be forward compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

C exposes `enumeration` values directly as integer while in C++ `enum` is a **real type**. Hence in C++ `enum` results in a **type check** while in C enum just represents constants of type int. Therefore integer and enum values can be intermixed in all the arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
enum answer {NO, YES};

enum gender {MALE, FEMALE};
```

with:

```
enum answer bla = YES; 
enum gender blop = MALE;
int bip = 0;
```

While not required by the C Standard, it allows the implementations to warn in the cases below:

```
bla = blop;

bip =  bla;
```

Note that `enum` types are arithmetic types and assignment between objects of different arithmetic types is always permitted but the implementation is still free to warn. As some mentioned the comments, the rules with `enum` types are different for C++.

**EDIT**: another example:

```
enum ans {
    YES,
    NO,
    MAYBE
};


enum ans a = /* initializer */;

switch (a)
{
    case YES:
        break;
    case NO:
        break;
}
```

With `-Wall` (that is `-Wswitch`),  `gcc` is able to warn that:

> tst.c:15:5: warning: enumeration value ‘MAYBE’ not handled in switch

If you had:

```
enum {
    YES,
    NO,
    MAYBE
};

int a = /* initializer */;
```

`gcc` would not be able to warn. So actually using the `enum` type instead of only the `enum` constant helps static analyzer tools.