# Enum as parameter of function in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

Can somebody give me an example where we really need an enum to be a parameter in function?

Comment: How do you differentiate "need" and "really need"?

Comment: I think you would better help yourself by asking a different question.   The reason for using an enum as a function parameter is the same as the reason for using an enum anywhere else in your code.

Comment: "really need" is too strong; you never do, but using them can make your code clearer, easier to maintain, and less bug-prone (especially in C++)

Answer (score 5):

Besides making code clearer, in C++ it enforces at compile time that a function **only** work with one out of a set of possible values:

```
namespace Foo
{
enum Bar { A, B, C };

void foo(Bar b) { .... }
void foo2(int i) { /* only ints between 0 and 5 make sense */ }
}


int main()
{
  Foo::Bar b = Foo::A;
  Foo::foo(b);   // OK
  Foo::foo(245); // Compile-time error!
  Foo::foo2(6);  // Compiles, triggering some run-time error or UB 
}
```

Comment: True of C++ but not of C which does not enforce type checking of enum types. A C compiler may however issue a warning, but may not do so as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597426/enum-type-check-in-c-gcc

Comment: @Clifford thanks for pointing that out. I hadn't realised the question was about two different languages, which is nonsense.

Comment: "nonsense" may be a bit strong - the languages share some identical syntax and are interoperable, it is perhaps naive but not unreasonable to assume identical semantics for the same syntax - the gotcha being they are not identical.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for enums, but they make software more readable. Example:

```
void write( const std::string&, bool flush );
```

And now the calling side:

```
write( "Hello World", true );
```

If an enum had been used, on the calling side it becomes more clearly what the second parameter means:

```
enum flush_type { flush, no_flush };
void write( const std::string&, flush_type flush );
```

and again the calling side:

```
write( "Hello World", flush );
```

Comment: Not really, the use of enumerations limits what you can pass as function argument to values of the enumeration.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Exactly. What should the function do with an unanticipated value? Enums help clarify what the function has been designed to do.

Comment: @PontusGagge and may force a compiler error, as in the example in my answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Only forces an error in C++.

Answer (score 0):

The function setColor in button, need to get parameter color, which sould be enum.

Comment: Note that every enum is equivalet to consts in the machine language