# How to define a generic data type containing enums in C?

Tags: c, oop, enums

I am trying to define a generic macro in c which does a state transition in a state machine and "logs" some data on the state transition (reason of the transition and the number of transitions done).

As this approach shall be used in multiple state machines i want to use a generic macro like:

```
#define STATE_TRANSITION(state_variable, new_state, reason)  /
    state_variable.state = new_state;   /          /* new_state is an enum value */
    state_variable.transition_reason = reason; /   /* reason is an enum value */
    state_variable.state_transition_counter++;     /* the counter may overflow */
```

To make this possible i am thinking of a state type like this

```
struct specific_state {
    enum POSSIBLE_STATES state;
    enum STATE_TRANSITION_REASONS transition_reason;
    uint8 state_transition_counter;
}
```

which can be used for a specific state machine.

To make sure that every state uses the same structure (to make the macro work) i try to use some parent type for a state.
My problem is that enum POSSIBLE_STATES and enum STATE_TRANSITION_REASONS can vary for the different statemachines.
But the only generic member in my struct would be state_transition_counter :)

My question is now:

Is there a possibility to define a type in c which represents a base "class" like:

```
struct debuggable_state {
    enum state;
    enum transition_reason;
    uint8 state_transition_counter;
}
```

which can be subclassed afterwards (to apply the specific enum types)?

Perhaps i will replace the macro by an inline function to make it type safe, but i am still not sure if my approach is possible at all.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but besides that the line continuation characters is wrong (it's the backslash \\), you should be careful with multi-statement macros like yours. What if you put it in a `if` statement, and forget the curly-braces around it?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, but have you tried unions?

Comment: It's best to always put complex macros in a do while(0)

Comment: Related to your problem, you do know that *any* enumeration value can be implicitly converted to `int`?

Comment: To solve the x not the y, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371460/state-machines-tutorials

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Only the simplest questions and the most obvious ones can be labelled "x y" problems. This isn't one of them.

Comment: @simonzack I didn't say it was, I was just suggesting an alternative for the x that would avoid the issue.

Comment: @Joachim and Jonathon: Thanks for the comments, you are right. I am just using pseudo code here.

Comment: @Joachim: I think the compiler will throw a warning because of the type mismatch? I know the an enum is just an int (depending on the compiler/platform).

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: I am dealing with embedded legacy code and i want to ease debugging at the moment. Perhaps i will rewrite the state machines in a seconds step. At the moment this is not my target.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Concerning your first comment: I am not sure if i understand that right, but then i would repeat my self a lot. And i want to avoid that.

Comment: why do you want to use a base class? Let's say you define two structs state_foo and state_bar, your macro would work without base class, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But with a base class i cannot forget to define a member. Of course this is more a question regarding c language than a question of realization.

Comment: That does not make sense, your macro will not compile if you forget to define a member. A base class is not possible here, since you want to use a different enum for each struct.

Comment: You are right! And this answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: the struct specific_state should not be trying to define enum(s). Which it is currently doing.  Rather make the first two entries 'int' , which will translate correctly for any enum.  and wrap the statements of the macro in do { ... } while(0); so they will be treated as a single code block.

Comment: Glad it helped :) By the way, when using comments on stackoverflow, you should use (for example to address me) "@Étienne", then I would get a notification that you answered. (You get notified that I commented because you wrote the question).

Comment: @user3629249: If i use ints the macro could be fed with any int value, also values which are not part of the state's enum (POSSIBLE_STATES). I would like to allow only values of the enum of the state.

Comment: @maggie Don't forget enums are not type-safe in C (unlike in C++), you can assign any value to an enum, the compiler will not complain. You will have to check manually that a valid value is being assigned if that's what you want.

Comment: @Étienne: Oh, i was not aware of this! Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

You could use int instead of the enums in the generic struct, the enums are represented as int anyway..