# Finite State Machine In C

Tags: c, switch-statement, state-machine

I am trying to create a simple finite state machine in C and I'm quite confused on how to get started. I tried looking online but nothing has really cleared this up for me.

My goal is to check if a string is octal, hex or a decimal.

To be octal the string must start with a 0, followed by digits 0-7.
To be hex the string must start with 0x or OX, followed by (a-f, A-F, 0-9)

My attempt at creating the states would be:

```
typedef enum  {
   ERROR,
   OCTAL,
   HEX,
   DECIMAL
} stringStates;
```

Now, I would then use a switch statement to go through the entirety of the string and switch between the different states until I have correctly identified which state it belongs to.

```
 while (current_Position<=end_String-1)
 {
    switch( "input something here")
      {
        case 0:
             //process string
             break;
        case 1:
             //process string
             break;

         case 2:
             //process string
             break;
         case 3:
             //process string
             break;
         default:
             break;
      }
  }
```

This concept is still very new to me and I'm having hard time understanding its implementation. If anyone can shed some light, it'll be much appreciated.

Comment: What about drawing a diagram 1st? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)

Comment: Take a look at this my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371460/state-machines-tutorials/1371654#1371654

Comment: There's more than one way to do it. How comfortable are you with function pointers?

Comment: Also "*`OCTAL`, `HEX`, `INTEGER`*": How the the latter compare to/differ from  the former two? Did you probably mean `DECIMAL` instead of `INTEGER`?

Comment: Decide your input set first, and then draw a state diagram or a transition table.

Comment: Also^2 you most likely need a state to start from, which would be which of the listed ones?

Comment: Nitpicking cont/: octals and hex numbers can be integers as well.

Comment: Ah yes, well I should change Integer to Decimal. I drew out the different states on paper, it's just its implementation that is confusing me.

Comment: why do you think you need a state machine ? I wouldn't implement a state machine for this use case... see [the definition of a state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)

Comment: As the code gets more complicated, like adding to check for floats, I can see my code becoming quite a long sequence of if-else statements. It gets the job done, but lacks efficiency. I want to try and implement a state machine design for both clarity and learning purposes.

Comment: why floats are adding complexity ? they should no. you should have a list of valid chars for decimals. a list of valid chars for hex and a list of valid chars for octals. then check for the 1 or 2 first chars in order to detect the type, and confirm validity of the number by comparing the rest of the strig with the valid chars associated with the detected type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647631/c-state-machine-design?rq=1 ?

Comment: @AymanKhamouma: The task is parsing. Parsing can be implemented using a state-machine.

Comment: @alk yes it can. but for this use case does it really need a state machine ? allow me to doubt. but I guess this is personal point of view...

Comment: Please do not change your question after answers/comments had been given. This might render such as ununderstandable. Add edits/updates as additions.

Comment: @Bret furthermore, you are confusing the result with the states... octal, hex, decimal should be the end-result of your state machine.not its states

Comment: @Bret States should be seen as "atomic" actions that will help you process a complex task.

Comment: Oh ok, so the states would be more like: FirstDigit, FirstTwoDigits (to check for hex) etc.

Comment: not really, I explained it in my answer, see below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a pretty much straight forward question and the solution is also very simple.

I have 7 states namely from 0 to 6 as shown by diagram.0 is the initial state. 3,4,5 could be the final states and 6 is the dead state.

[image]

**state 0**: Initial state and from this state we can only encounter following chars:

**0**  or  **O** or  **1-9**

if any other char then an error is there and no need to process further.

**state 1**: if char from state 0 is **0** then this is the next state and

if char from this state is **x** then the string is hexadecimal(state=4) and no need to process further as any char can follow.

if char from this state is 0-7 then string is octal(state=5) and we process till the end of string to see if we get any char different from 0-7, if we do then error is there as invalid string and no need to process further as soon as we get it.

**state 2**: if char from state 0 is O then this is the next state and from this state if next char is X then string is hexadecimal(state=4) and no need to process further, if it is not then error is there.

**state 3**: if char from state 0 is 1-9 then string is decimal number(state=3) and we process till the end of string to see if we get any char different from 0-9, if we do then error is there as invalid string and no need to process further as soon as we get it.

**state 4**:hexadecimal number

**state 5**:octal number

**state 6**:error meaning invalid string

Here is the C code. I have taken the length of the string to be 9, just for simplicity and nothing else.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  char *a="066676777";
  int state=0;int i=0;
  while(state!=6&&i<9)
  {
      switch(state)
      {
      case 0:
        if(a[i]=='0')
            state=1;
        else if(a[i]=='O')
            state=2;
        else if(a[i]>=49&&a[i]<=57)
            state=3;
        else {state=6;i=9;}
        break;
      case 1:
         if(a[i]=='x')
         {
              state=4;i=9;
         }
         else if(a[i]>=48&&a[i]<=55)
         {
             state=5;
             while(i<9)
                if(a[i]>=48&&a[i]<=55)
                 ++i;
                else {state=6;i=9;}
         }
         else {state=6;i=9;}
         break;
      case 2:
          if(a[i]=='X')
          {
              state=4;i=9;
          }
          else {state=6;i=9;}
         break;
      case 3:
          while(i<9)
            if(a[i]>=48&&a[i]<=57)
                ++i;
            else {state=6;i=9;}
            break;
      default:
        printf("please select correct initial state");
         break;
      }
      ++i;
    }
    if(state==3)
      printf("it is a decimal number");
    else if(state==4)
      printf("it is a hexadecimal number");
    else if(state==5)
      printf("it is a octal number");
    else printf("error encountered as invalid string");
}
```