# What is a state machine in terms of JavaScript promises and C# asyc-await?

Tags: javascript, c#, promise, async-await

I'm currently looking at `async-await` in C#, and noticed similarities to JavaScript promises. Looking into this I see that JavaScript is also going to support `async-await` statements, and that there are similarities between this and promises (look [at this blog post](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8#.dswrmzrk9) for example).

On a whim, I wondered what JavaScript's implementation of `async-await` was and found this question ([Java Equivalent of C# async/await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539245/java-equivalent-of-c-sharp-async-await)).

The accepted answer suggests that `async-await` (and by extension, I guess, promises) are implementations of a 'state machine'.

**Question:** What is meant by a 'state machine' in terms of promises, and are JavaScript promises comparable to C#'s `async-await`?

Comment: I recently read a question on here that asked about the implementation of .Net`yield` and `async/await`. The answer discussed both in terms of state machines along with some pseudo code. I'm not sure if it was a recent question though. (I might have navigated to it by chance). It wouldn't necessarily answer your question but it was a very good read on the matter, I just can't seem to find it (searching on my phone). Perhaps someone with better search skills can locate it knowing the subject matter.

Comment: This is how I came here https://twitter.com/rauschma/status/1026954063924084737 (Axel Rauschmayer twitting among others about target of transpilation for NPM packages)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JavaScript promises are comparable to C# `Task` objects which have a `ContinueWith` function that behaves like `.then` in JavaScript.

By "state machines" it is means that they are typically implemented by a state and a switch statement. The states are places the function can be at when it runs synchronously. I think it's better to see how such a transformation works in practice. For example let's say that your runtime only understands regular functions. An async function looks something like:

```
async function foo(x) {
   let y = x + 5;
   let a = await somethingAsync(y);
   let b = await somethingAsync2(a);
   return b;
}
```

Now, let's look at all the places the function can be when it executes a step synchronously:

```
async function foo(x) {
   // 1. first stage, initial
   let y = x + 5;
   let a = await somethingAsync(y);
   // 2. after first await
   let b = await somethingAsync2(a);
   // 3. after second await
   return b;
   // 4. done, with result `c`.
}
```

Now, since our runtime only understands synchronous functions - our compiler needs to do something to make that code into a synchronous function. We can make it a regular function and keep state perhaps?

```
let state = 1;
let waitedFor = null; // nothing waited for
let waitedForValue = null; // nothing to get from await yet.
function foo(x) {
   switch(state) {
      case 1: { 
        var y = x + 5;
        var a;
        waitedFor = somethingAsync(y); // set what we're waiting for
        return;
      }
      case 2: {
         var a = waitedForValue; 
         var b;
         waitedFor = somethingAsync(a);
         return;
      }
      case 3: {
        b = waitedFor;
        returnValue = b; // where do we put this?
        return;
      }
      default: throw new Error("Shouldn't get here");
   }
}
```

Now, it's somewhat useful, but doesn't do anything too interesting - we need to actually run this as a function. Let's put the state in a wrapper and automatically run the promises when they're resolved:

```
function foo(x) { // note, not async
  // we keep our state
  let state = 1, numStates = 3;
  let waitedFor = null; // nothing waited for
  let waitedForValue = null, returnValue = null; // nothing to get from await yet.
  // and our modified function
  function stateMachine() {
    switch(state) {
      case 1: { 
        var y = x + 5;
        var a;
        waitedFor = somethingAsync(y); // set what we're waiting for
        return;
      }
      case 2: {
         var a = waitedForValue; 
         var b;
         waitedFor = somethingAsync(a);
         return;
      }
      case 3: { 
        b = waitedFor;
        returnValue = b; // where do we put this?
        return;
      }
      default: throw new Error("Shouldn't get here");
   }
   // let's keep a promise for the return value;
   let resolve, p = new Promise(r => resolve = r); // keep a reference to the resolve
    // now let's kickStart it
   Promise.resolve().then(function pump(value) {
      stateMachine();
      state++; // the next state has progressed
      if(state === numStates) resolve(returnValue); // return the value
      return Promise.resolve(waitedFor).then(pump);
   }); 
   return p; // return the promise
}
```

Effectively, the `Promise.resolve().then(...` part calls the stateMachine and waits for the value that's being awaited every time until it is at the final state at which point it resolves the (returned beforehand) promise.

This is effectively [what Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2017%2Clatest%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&code=async%20function%20foo(x)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20y%20%3D%20x%20%2B%205%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20a%20%3D%20await%20somethingAsync(y)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20b%20%3D%20await%20somethingAsync2(a)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20c%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D) or [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=async%20function%20foo(x)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20y%20%3D%20x%20%2B%205%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20a%20%3D%20await%20somethingAsync(y)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20b%20%3D%20await%20somethingAsync2(a)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20c%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D) do with your code too. What the C# compiler does is very close - with the biggest difference is that it's put in a class.

Note we are ignoring conditionals, exceptions and loops here - it makes things a little bit more complicated but not much harder (you just need to handle each case separately).

Comment: Thank you. As someone new to the idea of 'State machines' in general, this is a good question to read about prior to reading this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100824/finite-state-machine-in-c

Comment: Is it correct to say that a state machine is effectively `the theoretical mapping of all of a program's possible conditions in terms of the operations that program can perform`?

Comment: A state machine in this context is just something that transitions between "states" (in this case, the parts of the switch statement).

Comment: Would it be correct to say that a state machine in itself is an 'abstract concept', meaning that it is only a representation of logic? Can I say that the switch statement is the implementation of the state machine?